# How do I install Ruby on Mac Leopard?

Tags: ruby, installation

Can anyone please give directions on how to install ruby 1.9 I tried installation directions given all over the web. Can't get it to work. Please kindly give step by step direction. I tried using macports but everytime I type in ruby -v it gives me 1.8.6.

Comment: Found the answer, anyone interested please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243088/

Answer (score 19):

[rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) is easiest way to manage your ruby installation on OSX.

If you are using rvm, you will able to install 1.9.1, 1.9.2, jruby, ree by typing `rvm install 1.9.1`

type `rvm default` to reset your ruby version back to 1.8.6

How to install rvm

```
sudo gem install rvm -s http://gemcutter.org/

rvm-install

rvm install 1.9.1

rvm use 1.9.1

ruby -v  # show ruby 1.9.1 version

rvm default

ruby -v  # show ruby 1.8.6 version
```

cheers

Comment: Hi Bry4n,

Tried but encounter a block, please help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209269/about-ruby-version-manager-installation

Comment: It appears the installation instructions above may be outdated; For latest RVM installation instructions see: https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

Comment: ~/.rvm/bin/rvm-installer ; you will probably have to add rvm to path yourself

Answer (score 13):

Install [Homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew).

`brew install ruby` installs the [current stable version](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) of ruby.

Comment: this installs 1.9.2 (current version) for me but `ruby -v` still shows 1.8.7. How do I make Homebrew's version my "default"?

Comment: @macek, make sure /usr/local/bin or where ever you chose to install Homebrew is in your PATH

Answer (score 7):

Use [Ruby Version Manager](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). It will allow you to install most versions of Ruby and help you manage gems across them.

Answer (score 4):

Ok this is how I remember doing it

2. Install Macports
3. Type `sudo port install ruby19`
4. Make sure that `/opt/local/bin` is in your path. If not add it.
5. Now to use ruby1.9 you type `ruby1.9 example.rb`

Also additionally if you dont want to use `ruby` command to use the default version. You can create a simple symlink in which make the ruby at `/usr/bin/ruby` point to `/opt/local/bin/ruby1.9`.

That way your ruby version will be 1.9. However I dont recommend doing that. As there are certain gems, that might not work with 1.9, which might be affected

Comment: can you please give direction on how to make sure that /opt/local/bin is in your path.

Comment: fire up the terminsal and type `echo $PATH`, if you see /opt/local/bin there you are fine.To ad it to your PATH this article will help `http://hayne.net/MacDev/Notes/unixFAQ.html#executionPath`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you ever solved this.  But it sounds like 1 of 2 problems:

**1.  You installed the wrong ruby with MacPorts**

if you just ran  `port install ruby`, then you installed the old version, which explains why `ruby -v` still shows 1.8.6.

If you ran `port install ruby19`, then you installed ruby 1.9, but under the name ruby19.  To access it, you'd have to type `ruby19` in place of `ruby`...so `ruby19 script/generate`, `ruby19 -v`...etc.

To fix that you can do `port install ruby19+nosuffix`

**2.  you still have your PATH set to the old Ruby, which is why you're getting 1.8.6 on `ruby -v`.**

First you gotta figure out where OSX is looking for your ruby by typing `which ruby`.  If you're using MacPorts, that command should return `/opt/local/bin/ruby`.  If `which ruby` returns `/usr/bin/ruby`, then it's still finding the default ruby that comes with OSX, which is 1.8.6.

To change your PATH, go open up .bash_profile, located in your user folder (if you have textmate, you can do `mate` ~/.bash_profile).  Add in this line and save:

```
echo PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/bin:$PATH"
```

Basically you add the MacPorts ruby into your PATH, so the system looks for ruby in the `/opt` folder too.  Also, maybe more importantly, you put the MacPorts path in front of the default PATH, so it will find that one first.

Goodluck with that.  Personally though, I vote for [Homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew).  You can find my setup for that at my [blog](http://rails-station-blog.heroku.com/2010/02/25/setting-up-rails-with-homebrew/).

Comment: Hi FunkyMunky,

Great Blog, ran into a block, not sure if I messed up my system files already, but this is the error I get:

kapplej-4:homebrew Home$ curl -L http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0   121    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0tar: homebrew: Cannot chdir: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: 22  283k   22 66374    0     0   182k      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  182k
curl: (23) Failed writing body
kapplej-4:homebrew Home$

Comment: Hey Ken.  Not entirely sure what your error is, but the instructions on that blog are a little outdated now.  For updated instructions go to the [website](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew).  I'd recommend running the script under 'Quick Install to /usr/local' unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

On my MacBook Pro I just did a good old compile and install.  Download the 1.9.1 source from the Ruby web site (www.ruby-lang.org) and then compile.  It'll install to /usr/local/bin so you will not corrupt the 1.8 if you wanted to revert back.

I never used the ports myself, but I know a lot that have/do.  http://hivelogic.com/articles/ruby-rails-leopard  is a good online guide for people not familiar with compiling and installing from source code.

Answer (score 1):

Just had to do this on a factory-fresh Mac last night, and it's gotten slightly more complicated recently. GCC is no longer directly supported by Apple, as they prefer Clang, and Xcode 4.3+ requires the command line tools to be installed separately before you can access Clang from the terminal. So here goes!

1.) Install XCode.(it's free!)

2.) Install RVM. Go to a terminal window and enter:

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

3a.) If you've installed XCode before 4.3, skip this step. Go to Xcode>Preferences>Downloads tab and install the XCode command Line Tools. This will let you access clang from Terminal.

3.)Open up terminal and enter:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

this will install ruby 1.9.3 in OSX

Answer (score 0):

You can use the one-click-installer :

http://rubyosx.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score -1):

1. Install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)
2. Type `port install ruby19`

Comment: I get the following error:

kapplej-4:~ Home$ port install ruby19
Warning: MacPorts running without privileges. You may be unable to complete certain actions (e.g. install).
--->  Computing dependencies for ruby19
--->  Dependencies to be installed: libiconv gperf ncurses ncursesw openssl zlib readline
--->  Installing gperf @3.0.4_0
Error: Target org.macports.install returned: MacPorts requires root privileges for this action
Error: The following dependencies failed to build: libiconv gperf ncurses ncursesw openssl zlib readline

Comment: Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
kapplej-4:~ Home$ ruby-v
-bash: ruby-v: command not found